# Sorting using sortBy method not working in underscore

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I am trying to sort an array of objects using underscore sortBy method the json is as follows

```js
[
   {
      "styleId": 91,
      "styleName": "Style Label",
      "dataSourceId": 1,
      "dataSourceName": null,
      "stationeryId": 1,
      "stationeryName": null,
      "styleType": 1,
      "styleTypeName": "Labels",
      "isActive": true,
      "isPlainPaper": true,
      "isSystemMaintained": false,
      "isPublished": true,
      "designerUrl": null,
      "sourceStyleId": 0,
      "rowIndicatorCode": 2,
      "isDefault": null,
      "hasElement": true,
      "styleDesign": null,
      "createdBy": "real",
      "createdDate": 1494217733790,
      "modifiedBy": "superuser",
      "modifiedDate": 1494388952450,
      "rowVersion": "AAAAAAIC8ls="
   },
   {
      "styleId": 69,
      "styleName": "irtest",
      "dataSourceId": 1,
      "dataSourceName": null,
      "stationeryId": 16,
      "stationeryName": null,
      "styleType": 1,
      "styleTypeName": "Labels",
      "isActive": true,
      "isPlainPaper": false,
      "isSystemMaintained": false,
      "isPublished": true,
      "designerUrl": null,
      "sourceStyleId": 0,
      "rowIndicatorCode": 2,
      "isDefault": null,
      "hasElement": false,
      "styleDesign": null,
      "createdBy": "arun",
      "createdDate": 1493288218843,
      "modifiedBy": "real",
      "modifiedDate": 1494062410107,
      "rowVersion": "AAAAAAHZaDk="
   },
   {
      "styleId": 21,
      "styleName": "new style-copy",
      "dataSourceId": 1,
      "dataSourceName": null,
      "stationeryId": 5,
      "stationeryName": null,
      "styleType": 1,
      "styleTypeName": "Labels",
      "isActive": true,
      "isPlainPaper": false,
      "isSystemMaintained": false,
      "isPublished": true,
      "designerUrl": null,
      "sourceStyleId": 0,
      "rowIndicatorCode": 2,
      "isDefault": null,
      "hasElement": true,
      "styleDesign": null,
      "createdBy": "Nandita",
      "createdDate": 1493186162607,
      "modifiedBy": "Nandita",
      "modifiedDate": 1493186173807,
      "rowVersion": "AAAAAAEXEwI="
   },
   {
      "styleId": 97,
      "styleName": "style 1",
      "dataSourceId": 1,
      "dataSourceName": null,
      "stationeryId": 1,
      "stationeryName": null,
      "styleType": 1,
      "styleTypeName": "Labels",
      "isActive": true,
      "isPlainPaper": true,
      "isSystemMaintained": false,
      "isPublished": true,
      "designerUrl": null,
      "sourceStyleId": 0,
      "rowIndicatorCode": 2,
      "isDefault": null,
      "hasElement": true,
      "styleDesign": null,
      "createdBy": "real",
      "createdDate": 1494646737753,
      "modifiedBy": "real",
      "modifiedDate": 1494647127567,
      "rowVersion": "AAAAAAIxLKM="
   }
]
```

This is my sample json I am trying to sort this json by the field styleName like`

```
var result = _.sortBy(ctrl.styles, function (o) { return o.styleName; });
```

Result am getting is as follows

```js
[
   {
      "styleId": 21,
      "styleName": "new style-copy",
      "dataSourceId": 1,
      "dataSourceName": null,
      "stationeryId": 5,
      "stationeryName": null,
      "styleType": 1,
      "styleTypeName": "Labels",
      "isActive": true,
      "isPlainPaper": false,
      "isSystemMaintained": false,
      "isPublished": true,
      "designerUrl": null,
      "sourceStyleId": 0,
      "rowIndicatorCode": 2,
      "isDefault": null,
      "hasElement": true,
      "styleDesign": null,
      "createdBy": "Nandita",
      "createdDate": 1493186162607,
      "modifiedBy": "Nandita",
      "modifiedDate": 1493186173807,
      "rowVersion": "AAAAAAEXEwI="
   },
   {
      "styleId": 69,
      "styleName": "irtest",
      "dataSourceId": 1,
      "dataSourceName": null,
      "stationeryId": 16,
      "stationeryName": null,
      "styleType": 1,
      "styleTypeName": "Labels",
      "isActive": true,
      "isPlainPaper": false,
      "isSystemMaintained": false,
      "isPublished": true,
      "designerUrl": null,
      "sourceStyleId": 0,
      "rowIndicatorCode": 2,
      "isDefault": null,
      "hasElement": false,
      "styleDesign": null,
      "createdBy": "arun",
      "createdDate": 1493288218843,
      "modifiedBy": "real",
      "modifiedDate": 1494062410107,
      "rowVersion": "AAAAAAHZaDk="
   },
   {
      "styleId": 91,
      "styleName": "Style Label",
      "dataSourceId": 1,
      "dataSourceName": null,
      "stationeryId": 1,
      "stationeryName": null,
      "styleType": 1,
      "styleTypeName": "Labels",
      "isActive": true,
      "isPlainPaper": true,
      "isSystemMaintained": false,
      "isPublished": true,
      "designerUrl": null,
      "sourceStyleId": 0,
      "rowIndicatorCode": 2,
      "isDefault": null,
      "hasElement": true,
      "styleDesign": null,
      "createdBy": "real",
      "createdDate": 1494217733790,
      "modifiedBy": "superuser",
      "modifiedDate": 1494388952450,
      "rowVersion": "AAAAAAIC8ls="
   },
   {
      "styleId": 97,
      "styleName": "style 1",
      "dataSourceId": 1,
      "dataSourceName": null,
      "stationeryId": 1,
      "stationeryName": null,
      "styleType": 1,
      "styleTypeName": "Labels",
      "isActive": true,
      "isPlainPaper": true,
      "isSystemMaintained": false,
      "isPublished": true,
      "designerUrl": null,
      "sourceStyleId": 0,
      "rowIndicatorCode": 2,
      "isDefault": null,
      "hasElement": true,
      "styleDesign": null,
      "createdBy": "real",
      "createdDate": 1494646737753,
      "modifiedBy": "real",
      "modifiedDate": 1494647127567,
      "rowVersion": "AAAAAAIxLKM="
   }
]
```

where ctrl.styles is the above JSON, Is there something am doing wrong?

Comment: What output are you expecting and what output are you getting?

Comment: I have updated the question with the result that am currently having, expected  result will be sorted array by styleName where styleName starting with 'a' at the start and 'z' at the end

Comment: When I paste your array into dev tools on underscore's web site and sort using your code it seems to return the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36442564/3819411) and correcting return value, I found this works for me:(I suppresed array and named it as `arr` instead of `ctrl.styles`)

```
var res = _.sortBy(arr, function (a) {
    var x=  _.map(a.styleName.split(''), function (i) {
        return i.charCodeAt(0);
    }).join('');
    return x;
});
```

or as @ArunBabuVijayanath said in comments:

```
var res = _.sortBy(arr, function (a) {
    return a.styleName.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: A better solution would be var result = _.sortBy(ctrl.styleName, function (a) { return a.styleName.toUpperCase(); });

Answer (score 5):

```
var result =  _.sortBy(ctrl.styles, function (a) { return a.styleName.toUpperCase(); });
```

The problem I was facing was the styleName where having different case, converting styleName to uppercase solved the problem. Yashar's answer also solved the issue